# Angularjs check item stock message in ng-repeat, display message in right item index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show a stock message whether the item has enough `quantity` in the API object for the user to add the right amount of `quantity` in the basket. Managed to do it with single item but since the items in the basket is an `Array` having an issue to show the stock message on the right item index in `ng-repeat`

HTML template code : --

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.basketList">
 ...
 <button ng-click="vm.update(item)">Update qty</button>
 // stock message
 <span ng-if="vm.checkStock == false" class="text-warning">Stock is not enough.</span>
</div>
```

controller update qty: --

```
vm.update = function (item) {

 // Will be needing this var for later
  var updateCartItem = {
      ....
      Products: [item]
   }

// Date required for HTTP stock check
   var xd = {
        ...
        ProductIds: [updateCartItem.Products[0].product_idField]
   }
itemService.itemStock(xd)
  .then(function (response) {
     console.log('Checking stock...');

  for (var i = 0; i < response.data.Results.length; i++) {
      var stockElement = response.data.Results[i];
     if (stockElement.qtyField >= updateCartItem.Products[0].qtyField) {
        console.log('Stock is enough go ahead update QTY');
            vm.checkStock = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Stock is not enough');
        vm.checkStock = false;
      }
  }

}
```

Here's an image of I'm trying to achieve, I marked them as cross and check (cross = not enough stock, check = enough stock so to update). So message `not enough stock` should only show on the item with cross.
[image]

My question is how do I show the message in the correct index for item that doesn't have enough stock, when I click the button to update the `qty`?

Hope this question make sense to some and would be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have **checkStock** property on item.

```
vm.checkStock = false;
// make this
item.checkStock = false
```

In repeater

```
<span ng-if="vm.checkStock == false" class="text-warning">Stock is not enough.</span>
```

Change this to

```
<span ng-if="item.checkStock == false" class="text-warning">Stock is not enough.</span>
```

Comment: what -.- I tried that earlier and it didn't work. I guess because of the extra `if()` I had but I removed it when I post the question. Seems to be working :)

Comment: but it doesn't remove the message when the stock qty is within the stock value.

Comment: vm.checkStock = true --> item.checkStock=true, did you change this? If yes then on update it should work.